# Print many small PDF pages on one regular page

Tags: pdf, printing

I have a pdf file containing small pages, size 6cm by 8cm. I'd like to print them on A4 paper, in 3x3 grids.

If I combine the n-up parameter of my printer settings with 100% scale, I get miniatures, as the 6.5x9 are shrunk by the n-up factor.

If I combine the n-up parameter with fit-to-page, I get oversized print as they are first fitted to a whole A4 page then shrunk by the n-up factor. That's a 125% print.

I imagine I could use an application to do some sort of 3x3 grid repagination before printing but I don't know how.

Could you help? Linux-way preferred, Windows if need be.

Comment: My friend's comp prof used to say "always use your LaTex!" I suspect you should find an answer using some type of editor, maybe in TeX (there's even a whole SE site about it, with [Q's like this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105589/insert-pdf-file-in-latex-document), tried searching over there?) or some other PDF editor, word processor, etc

Comment: Convert to ps, then use `pstops` with custom scale and offset. Might need a bit of experimenting until the pages look like you want them to.

Comment: Are you familiar with Indesign? It could be made in InDesign pretty easily.

Comment: @Xen2050: I was talking (but didn't mention it) about an all gfx PDF file, so LaTeX is not easily involved. But, eventually, the solution I found is likend to it: `pdfjam`! So thanks.

Comment: @dirkt: Thanks to the pointer to `pstops` and the other `psutils`. I toyed with them and found a near solution. Unfortunately, I encounter some problem in the mandatory `pdf2ps` conversion that adds some extra margin around the pages!

Comment: @Yisroel: I used to use InDesign a lot but I don't have a license anymore, so this way can't be mine. Too bad.

Answer (score 3):

The solution I found is the `pdfjam` package, a pdf equivalent to `psutils`. All I need to do is this simple command:

```
$ pdfjam --nup 3x3 --noautoscale true --suffix 3by3 source-file.pdf
```

with

- `nup 3x3` in order to create the 3 by 3 grid
- `--noautoscale true` to avoid fit-to-page scaling
- `--suffix 3by3` so that the output file is named `source-file-3by3.pdf`

As a note, I alternatively could use `psnup` this way:

```
$ pdf2ps source-file.pdf - | psnup -9 -s1 -p a4 | ps2pdf - destination-file.pdf
```

- `-9` indicating to `psnup` I want to place 9 pages per page
- `-s1` forcing a 100% scale, keeping the original pages their original size
- `-p a4` for a4 output (beware on Debian, it is overridden by  `/etc/papersize`)

Unfortunately, the `pdf2ds` conversion puts margins all around the original pages, so a 3 by 3 grid does not fit anymore on an a4 page.